# How to search recent post for keywords on twitter with c#?

Tags: c#, twitter

I've made games with c# but have never done anything with networking or accessing a website via c#, so I was wondering how I would be able to search twitter post for certain keywords, counting how many come up but are recent post. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest that you'll check Linq to Twitter:

http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/

This website should get you on the right track with searching inside a post with Linq To Twitter:

http://geekswithblogs.net/WinAZ/archive/2011/04/28/displaying-search-results-with-linq-to-twitter-and-asp.net-mvc.aspx

Comment: Alright, I'm sad to say I have no idea how I'm suppose to download this and use it. I grabbed it and couldn't open it up without problems in visual studio. Thank you though.

Comment: Which problem are you having? I see that the latest version is from Tue Jan 24 2012 at 10:00 AM.